# How do I add different colours and show legend for plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting 4 different vectors in same graph. Although MATLAB is assigning them different colours, I want to assign them my own colours. How can I do this? I also want to show the legend. Here is my code:

```
%Plotting of final solutions
a = 0:h:5.01;
z=1:1:N+2;
%ex=exact
up=upwind(z,M+1);
lf = laxfriedrich(z,M+1);
lw = laxwendroff(z,M+1);
oo = otherone(z,M+1);
plot(a,up,'o',a,lf,'o',a,lw,'o',a,oo,'o');
%plot (a,lf,'o',a,oo,'o');
axis([0,5,-1,1]);
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) and [`legend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html)?

Comment: It would be better to ask the question like an FAQ question. So that others will profit from the Q and A more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify colours in many different ways, the simplest being:

```
plot(a, up, 'ro')
hold on
plot(a, lf, 'bo')
plot(a, lw, 'go')
plot(a, oo, 'yo')
legend;
```

Take a look in documentation for Plot > [LineSpec](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?searchHighlight=plot#inputarg_LineSpec) (and [colorspec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html) if you want more).